# An underbracket in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Good evening

I would like to get two brackets below a matrix (the picture below).

Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: also good Sunday evening! do you try anything? please show this.

Comment: No. I'm writing my maths notes to school. :) Can you help me?

Comment: It might be the simplest way to draw this matrix with help of `tikz` package and `matrix` library. See *TikZ & and PGF manual*, chapters 20 (Matrices and Alignment, page 305) and 57 (Matrix Library, page 646). There are lot of examples. If you will stuck in your effort to solve your problem yourself, people here will more willing to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't have many of these structures, you can do as follows: in the argument to `\underbrace` you repeat the part of the matrix the brace refers to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation*}
A=
\begin{gathered}[t]
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
11 & 2 & 3 & 44 & 5 
\end{array}\right)
\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\underbrace{\hphantom{%
  \begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  11 & 2 & 3
  \end{array}%
}}_{\text{some text}}
\hspace{2\arraycolsep}\hspace{\arrayrulewidth}
\underbrace{\hphantom{%
  \begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
  4 & 5 \\
  44 & 5
  \end{array}%
}}_{\text{text}}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]