# How to add label caption for this matrix?

Tags: captions, matrices, nicematrix

How can I add caption for this matrix like this?

[image]

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388138/labels-and-captions-of-a-matrix) but couldn't make it work for this case due to the A1/A2 at the begining.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\clr}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1}/\textcolor{blue}{#2}} 

\begin{document}

\[
\clr {A_1}{A_2}=\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
 & V_1& V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 & V_6 & V_7   \\
\begin{block}{c(ccccccc)}
V_1 &  \clr{0}{0} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_2 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}  \\
V_3 & \clr{1}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_4 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_5 & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0}   \\
V_6 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
V_7 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

And this is the matrix with nicematrix. I added it just in case that it is easier to add the caption than the blockarray.

```
\[
\clr {A_1}{A_2}=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
 & V_1& V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 & V_6 & V_7   \\
V_1 &  \clr{0}{0} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_2 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}  \\
V_3 & \clr{1}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_4 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_5 & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0}   \\
V_6 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
V_7 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a solution using `nicematrix`

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}% added 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}% added

\newcommand{\clr}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1}/\textcolor{blue}{#2}} 

\begin{document}
    
\[
\clr {A_1}{A_2}=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col, margin] % added margin
    & V_1& V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 & V_6 & V_7   \\
    V_1 &  \clr{0}{0} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
    V_2 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}  \\
    V_3 & \clr{1}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
    V_4 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} &\clr{0}{0}  & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
    V_5 & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0}   \\
    V_6 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
    V_7 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz
    \draw [decorate,decoration = {calligraphic brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt},thick]
    ([yshift=-5pt]last-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-5pt]last-7.south east)   node [black,midway,yshift=-18pt] {Some caption here};
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

**ADDED**

Adding `xshift` to both extremes allows to brace to encompass the whole matrix.

[image: d]

```
\[
\clr {A_1}{A_2}=\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col, margin] % added margin
    & V_1& V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 & V_6 & V_7   \\
    V_1 &  \clr{0}{0} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
    V_2 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}  \\
    V_3 & \clr{1}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
    V_4 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} &\clr{0}{0}  & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
    V_5 & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0}   \\
    V_6 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
    V_7 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz
    \draw [decorate,decoration = {calligraphic brace,mirror,amplitude=10pt},thick]
    ([yshift=-5pt,xshift=-25pt]last-1.south west) -- ([yshift=-5pt ,xshift=10pt]last-7.south east)   node [black,midway,yshift=-18pt] {Some caption here};
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]
```

Comment: Very nice, how can I make it fit the column width?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Please explain.

Comment: I meant to scale it down to fix the column width something like I adjustbox. Aw, probably I'll post a new question if I cound't solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Not the same as you want, but very close!
if I find the same solution I will edit my answer

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\clr}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1}/\textcolor{blue}{#2}} 
\newcommand\undermat[2]{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102468/5764
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{%
    \begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}_{\text{$#1$}}}$}#2}

\begin{document}
 \begin{equation*}
\clr {A_1}{A_2}=
\begin{array}{c}
%\underbrace{%
\begin{matrix}
\bordermatrix{& V_1& V_2 & V_3 & V_4 & V_5 & V_6 & V_7 \\
V_1 &  \clr{0}{0} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_2 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}  \\
V_3 & \clr{1}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_4 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} &\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} \\
V_5 & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0}   \\
V_6 & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{1} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{1}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}   \\
V_7 & \undermat{qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq}{\clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0} & \clr{0}{0}}}
\end{matrix}\\
%\textrm{This is $A$}\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this is that fences are too long which included the exterior row.